# How do I fill a header with a background color without defining a pixel height?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I was playing around with a responsive design and wanted to know how to fill the header with a background color without defining a pixel height - which I normally would do but is non-responsive.

My demo example is here and you can see I was trying to fill the header with a yellow

Comment: You have to clear the floats so that the header height is based on the content within the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `header{overflow: hidden;}` 
2)

```
header:after{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    }
```

Comment: thanks this works, I now understand I must clear both, I am not sure I understand why overflow: hidden worked though, I thought that was for "hiding" content when it went beyond

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick, but you may consider adding some padding too:

```
header {
  background-color: #FABA1A;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using float to the children elements so you need to clear them by using clearfix techniques which you may google that.

You may use `overflow:hidden;` for quick and nice solution

```
header {
    background-color: #faba1a;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could instead of setting a pixelated height set a percentage (of course, you'd then have to set the same div to an absolute positioning).

```
div {
 height: 10%;
 position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add rule

```
header {float: left;}
```

The issue is that your contents of the div are all floated so it's collapsing to 0  height. You can just fix this by floating the container too. Depends on what else you want to add really.